# Does republishing Asp.net core mvc app from visual studio to azure app service generate a new link to live website or same as previous?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created an ASP.NET Core MVC app in Visual Studio and published that to an Azure App service using the 'Publish' option in Visual Studio.

It generates a web link to access that app on the web, something like `23124131.azurewebsites.net`.

Now, I made some changes to my project in local machine and I was wondering if when I click the publish button, will it replace the previous project files in Azure and use the same link - or does it generate a new link?

The thing is I had a college test earlier where I had to submit link to web app.

Now if republish app from Visual Studio after making some changes, will the professor not be able to see it because it was modified after
and the link I submitted earlier points to new modified project?

Comment: will not change, default domain in azure web app is `webapp_name.azurewebsites.net`, if you don't change the web app name in azure, it won't change

Answer (score 1):

- Republishing Asp.net core mvc app from visual studio to azure app service does not generate new link.
- The existing App service will be updated with the new Files/Source.
- ***If you wish to change the website link, then***

Select Publish => New ,And give a new name to the App Service

[image]

- New App Service with new link will be generated.